# Sequelize: findAll based on param if param is not null and just findAll if param is null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get data using **Sequelize** in my **Express** app, and database using **MSSQL**. Here is my code :

```
getInstitution: function (req, res) {
    var type = req.query.type,
            limit = parseInt(req.query.limit),
            offset = parseInt(req.query.offset);

    Students.findAll({
        limit: limit,
        offset: offset,
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        where: {
            gender: type
        }
    })
}
```

Desc: 
Type => ( 1 is Male, 2 Female).

I can get students if `type`is not null and then I get the students based on the `type`, but how to get All students(male & female) if the `type` is null or doesn't contain any value?

I think it would work if I do check first, if `type` is not null call another function to find based on type, else call another function that find All.

Is there any better way to do that without using two another function above?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about applying conditional in just a where part?

```
getInstitution: function (req, res) {
  var type = req.query.type,
      limit = parseInt(req.query.limit),
      offset = parseInt(req.query.offset);

   Students.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    where: type ? { gender: type } : {}  // I think {} or null will work.
  })
}
```